# Swift: How to remove the .00 of NSNumberFormatter?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsnumberformatter

Someone helps me to make the textfield showing comma and $, but whenever there will always be .00 tailing the number even I delete all in the textfield. How to remove that if someone is only typing integer or nothing? Thanks a lot!

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let oldText = textField.text! as NSString
    var newText = oldText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string) as NSString!
    var newTextString = String(newText)

    let digits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()
    var digitText = ""
    for c in newTextString.unicodeScalars {
        if digits.longCharacterIsMember(c.value) {
            digitText.append(c)
        }
    }

    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    //        formatter.usesSignificantDigits = false
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
    let numberFromField = (NSString(string: digitText).doubleValue) / 100

    newText = formatter.stringFromNumber(numberFromField)

    textField.text = String(newText)

    return false

}
```

Comment: http://www.codingexplorer.com/getting-started-with-nsnumberformatter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {


    let oldText = textField.text! as NSString
    var newText = oldText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string) as NSString!
    var newTextString = String(newText)

    let digits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()
    var digitText = ""
    for c in newTextString.unicodeScalars {
        if digits.longCharacterIsMember(c.value) {
            digitText.append(c)
        }
    }

    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    //        formatter.usesSignificantDigits = false
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
    let numberFromField = (NSString(string: digitText).doubleValue) / 100

    newText = formatter.stringFromNumber(numberFromField)

    if newText .isEqualToString("$0.00") {

        newText = ""

    }

    textField.text = String(newText)

    return false

}
```

I have just added,

```
  if newText .isEqualToString("$0.00") {

        newText = ""

    }
```

in your method.

**Update :** (as asked in comment)

It's much simple replace your method with below one,

```
   func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {


    let oldText = textField.text! as NSString
    var newText = oldText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string) as NSString!
    var newTextString = String(newText)

    let digits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()
    var digitText = ""
    for c in newTextString.unicodeScalars {
        if digits.longCharacterIsMember(c.value) {
            digitText.append(c)
        }
    }

  //  let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    //        formatter.usesSignificantDigits = false
  //  formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
  //  formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")

    let numberFromField = (NSString(string: digitText).intValue)



    newText = NSString.localizedStringWithFormat("$%d", numberFromField)

 //        if newText .isEqualToString("$0.00") {
//            
//            newText = ""
//        
//        }

    textField.text = String(newText)

    return false

}
```

Comment: Hi, that is fine. How about when I type an integer and remove the decimal part finally?

Comment: If I want to type 100, the textfiled will show $100.00, how to make it into $100.

Answer (score 1):

set minimumFractionDigits and maximumFractionDigits of  NSNumberFormatter()::

```
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
```

Comment: If I set that, I cannot type in the textfield.